# Calendar.MONTH return 2. How to return 02

Tags: java

`String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)` return 1 instead of 01. How can I use this that result will be 02, 03, 04 and not 2, 3, 4

I know that `Calendar.MONTH` return numbers from 0 to 11

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a formatting issue. Why not investigate [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) ? Or [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) ?

(note that `SimpleDateFormat` has thread-safety issues and [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is a recommended alternative)

Answer (score 4):

You can use instead

```
String.format("%02d", ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

And I'd also recommend to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of the Java Calendar.